# Is “dass” correct in this sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clause

Regarding this sentence:

> Du hast immer Fragen gestellt und darauf bestanden, dass ich antworte.

I’m really confused because intuitively I would say that *dass* is right, but it doesn’t really initiate the subordinate clause, does it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may sound surprising, but the subclause marked by *dass* can in fact be governed by verb, a noun *or* a substituting pronoun.

Most common form:

> Ich verlange, dass du mir antwortest!

Subclause governed by noun:

> Die Vorstellung, dass ich dir antworte, ist abwegig.

Subclause governed by pronoun:

> Ich bestehe darauf, dass du mir antwortest!

The set of pronouns that work like this is small and closed, and they tend to be compounds of *da-*.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.
If it were *das* instead, what word would be targeted by the article/pronoun?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really see your problem, but of course there is a subordinate clause and it is initiated by *dass*. You can tell that it is one because:

- There is a subject (nominative *ich*) and a conjugated verb (*antworte*);
- if you extend it with an object, you realise that the verb is last:

  > […] dass ich *dir* antworte.

And it has to be *dass* (and not *das*) for a variety of reasons, including:

- There is no neuter word that is directly referenced. Compare:

  > Das Wort, das ich dir sage, ist die Antwort.
- It can stand all on its own which is not possible for relative clauses starting with *das*:

  > Was verlange ich?
  >   Dass ich dir antworte.
  >
  > Was ist mit dem Wort?
  >   <strike>Das ich dir sage.</strike>
  >   Das Wort, das ich dir sage, ist die Antwort.
- It cannot be replaced by *welches* (which is an almost certain indicator for *das* and not *dass*):

  > <strike>Du bestehst darauf, welches ich dir antworte.</strike>